# OpenAPI 3.0 - allOf inside oneOf

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

The following YAML:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: test
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      summary: test
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Test
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  - allOf:
                    - type: object
                      properties:
                        firstA:
                          type: string
                    - type: object
                      properties:
                        firstB:
                          type: string
                  - allOf:
                    - type: object
                      properties:
                        secondA:
                          type: string
                    - type: object
                      properties:
                        secondB:
                          type: string
```

Does not render at all in the [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io).

In [ReDoc](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc) it also fails to render properly:

[image]

---

If nesting multiple `allOf` instances directly inside of `oneOf` is invalid, how could I achieve the same result with a valid spec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReDoc author here.
It is a ReDoc bug. Your spec is valid.

It has been already fixed and will be available in `2.0.0-alpha.40`.

Comment: Odd thing is it looks like it's a bug in editor.swagger.io as well. Maybe just an edge case that got missed by both...