# using - oneOf, anyOf in Schema

Tags: openapi

I want to let user allow flexibility to provide only one of either `ref_id` or `dataCenter`. Could someone correct this schema ?

```
  kind: kind
    metadata:
      name: kind.v1
      namespace: system
    spec:
      descrption: This is an example specification 
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          ref_id:
            type: string
            minLength: 25
            maxLength: 40
          dataCenter:
            type: string
            enum:
              - "abc"
              - "xyzzy"
          version:
            type: integer
            example: 1
        required:
          - ref_id
          - dataCenter
          - version
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mutually exclusive properties in OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55615638/113116)

Comment: @Helen Yes it did and this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563638/openapi-3-0-allof-inside-oneof

Answer (score 0):

Because you have additional properties besides those two, a simple `oneOf` would be insufficient. Instead, nest a `oneOf` for `ref_id` and `dataCenter` inside an `allOf`.

(Example simplified for brevity)

```
properties:
  allOf:
    - version:
    - oneOf:
      - ref_id:
      - dataCenter:
```